# Django self referencing many-to-many model

Tags: django, recursion, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a simple Django Jobs model with two fields; applicants and applicants_selected.

"applicants" is a many to many relationship to the users model.
I want "applicants_selected" to be a many to many relationship to the applicants field of the same model

For Example:

```
class Job(models.Model):
       applicants = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True)
       selected_applicants = models.ManyToManyField('Self.applicants', blank=True)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `BooleanField` in the [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) of the `ManyToManyField`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):
    applicants = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='Applicant'
    )

class Applicant(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You thus can change the `selected` field to `True` in case the candidate is selected. You thus can select the applicants that are selected with:

```
myjob.applicants.filter(applicant__selected=True)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).